# put many websites behind a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a bunch of temporary domains as the following:

`app1.dummydomain.com
app2.dummydomain.com
app3.dummydomain.com
...`

these apps may reside on different servers with different IPs.

now I want to put all those apps behind the same reverse proxy and give them each a real domain like

`www.myapp1.com
www.myapp2.com
www.myapp3.com 
...`

when user browser opens any of the above domains, the request(https) first goes to the proxy, which then intelligently forwards the request to the right website.

What are the best ways to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the proxy? You can easily just point the DNS names to the real server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done rather easily using NGINX, but you'll need to keep in mind that all traffic will go through the reverse proxy, so it does put some demand on that machine. It's also fairly common to do SSL offloading to the reverse proxy, which moves the load of encryption to the reverse proxy instead.

Here's the official documentation for NGINX reverse proxy feature: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

But essentially it boils down to this in it's most simple form:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://someother.server.org:8000;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add some stuff to handle for example passing requests, handling SSL/TLS etc. Another thing to keep in mind is that you'll need a server block for each site coming in, if they aren't all being forwarded to the same place.